# ASP.Net MVC - Helper lambdaexpression post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods, strong-typing, nhlambdaextensions

I created this helper method using a lambdaexpression to used strongly type helper in a view

Helper

```
        public static string DateFor<TModel, TDate>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TDate>> expression)
        {
            ModelMetadata data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ...
            //code that creates three dropdownlist (day, month and year)
            ...
        }
```

view

```
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascita) %>
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Account MyAccount)
        {
            ...
            return View(...);
        }
```

my problem is that the MyAccount.DataNascita is not set with the value i choose in the Edit form (date's value minimun.. ex. 1900/01/01).

how to bind it in a Edit post action?

Comment: I cannot understand the question. `MyAccount.DataNascita is not set` do you mean the helper method does not return the value or the model does not populated on postback?

Comment: ....the model does not populated on postback!

Comment: now you understand? could you help me please? thanks.....

Comment: Yes but I expected a bit more politeness. I know you are not using web forms and there is no postback as such, but I asked if the data is loaded after the post to the controller.

Comment: sorry, i did not want to be rude but my English is not perfect:). however the property DataNascita (datetime type) is always 0001/01/01 after post to the controller, while other properties are properly valued... Sorry again!

Comment: As Tomas said, when you output to a label, this would not be able to post back the value. Alternative is to use a `TextBoxFor` and then optionally use JQuery to show a calendar for you. **The answer you have accepted is wrong, you would almost never need a custom ModelBinder.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is a custom ModelBinder that will parse the incoming posted data and convert it into a DateTime for your model.

Comment: thanks so much. I think so the way to go is the custom modelbinder! i found this: [link](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/03/templated-helpers-and-custom-model-binders-in-asp-net-mvc-2/)

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you say that you are outputting a *Label* for something, but your question concerns why the value isn't kept on *posting*.

I think you need to, at least, say `Html.EditorFor(...)`, but you probably want to use the helper method you wrote:

```
<%: Html.DateFor(model => model.DataNascita) %>
```

However, it is impossible to say exactly what is going on here without knowing the data type of the `DataNascita` property on the model.

Comment: MyAccount.DataNascita is a DateTime property. I created an helper because i want have a 3 dropdown list (with a unique helper) that corrispond at days, months and years. Yes, My question is how to mantain the values (set in a view on my helper) in a model during the post action

Comment: I think you should use the ability to create your own editortemplate here, and then make use of a modelbinder as Alberto suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

You can customize it with [Jquery Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).